# Limit of Decreasing Plot Size in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure

I use MATLAB R2021b. I have a 10x10 data array and I am using `contourf` function to plot the data. By default, MATLAB gives me a figure with 1120x840 pixels.

I know that I can use the command `set(gcf, 'position', [700, 700, 100, 100])` to decrease the size of the figure. And I get a figure with 200x200 pixels. I decided to shrink the value in the `set` function by half to get a 100x100 figure.

However, when I try to do `set(gcf, 'position', [700, 700, 50, 50])` , I got a figure with size 100x160. No matter how much further I decrease the value in the `set` function, the second dimension of the figure remained at 160 pixels. And there's no problem with the first dimension -- it can shrink with the value in the `set` function.

Does anyone know what's the problem here? My goal is to get a figure with 100x100 pixels.

Thank you very much for any advice!

Comment: in short you can't, the problem here is that matlab doesn't allow you to do it, an advice if you have to do it is to do the plotting in python using `matplotlib.contourf`, you can interface with python within matlab.

Comment: May I ask why MATLAB doesn't let me to do it? Is it because 100x100 is too small for a picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am the original poster. I think there is a minimum window size in both Windows and Mac operating systems. 100 pixels are smaller than the minimum windows size, so I cannot generate such a small figure.
This should be the answer for my question.

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB has always had a minimal size for figure windows. A smaller window cannot contain the minimal set of menus and toolbar buttons.

But you don’t need a small window to export a small plot.

When exporting a plot, MATLAB uses the [“PaperPosition” and “PaperUnits” figure properties](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.figure-properties.html#d124e449460). Set the units to pixels and the size to your required sizes to export the figure in those sizes.

There are of course other alternatives:

- Set the axes to your required sizes, then export only the axes area (or crop the produced image to size).
- Export a figure at twice (or four times) the size, then resample by a factor 1/2 (or 1/4).

---

If you’re not exporting, and just want a small display on the screen, consider putting multiple things in the same figure window, all you need to do is control the axes’s “Position” property.

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you show me a sample code on how to do that? When I use the "figure" function together with the contourf function, MATLAB always gives me two output figures but one being blank.

Comment: @Aurora7979 `contourf` plots to the current axes, it should not open a new window. The `figure` command opens a new figure window. If you want to use it, use it before plotting. But you don’t need to, you can adjust figure and axes properties with `set` like you are doing in the question.